# Can't disable logging of images with nginx

Tags: logging, nginx, configuration, config

I'm trying to disable the logging of images in nginx, but it doesn't seem to work.

I am running it on Windows and I have the following setup:

```
http {

  # directives omitted for brevity

  log_format      upstream_log_format '[$time_local] $status $remote_addr $request $http_referer "$http_user_agent" $upstream_addr $upstream_status $upstream_response_time $http_x_forwarded_for $cookie_cfid';
  access_log      C:/Logs/nginx/$host-access.log upstream_log_format;

  include site.conf;

  # directives omitted for brevity
}
```

then in site.conf I have

```
server {

    # directives omitted for brevity

    location ~  /res/ {

      expires     14d;
      access_log  off;
      break;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {

      expires     14d;
      access_log  off;
      break;
    }
}
```

But the images and files under /res/ are still logged.  I tried changing the order and moving the access_log directive in the main file around but that did not seem to make a difference.

### EDIT:

A more verbose configuration is available at https://gist.github.com/igal-getrailo/6981111 where the new directives for `access_log off;` were added at Line 30 of the 3rd file, i.e.  https://gist.github.com/igal-getrailo/6981111#file-3-nginx-site-site1-conf-L30
Any ideas?

Comment: Probably it's something in `# directives omitted for brevity`.

Comment: There is nothing else that relates to access_log, and I know that the location sections are found because the expires directive works properly.

Comment: There is nothing about access log

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right.  The new directives for `access_log off;` were added at https://gist.github.com/igal-getrailo/6981111#file-3-nginx-site-site1-conf-L30

Comment: Have you reload/restart nginx?

Comment: of course, many times.